# Changed load behavior in WPF app after upgrading PRISM from 4 to 6.1?

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-4, prism-6

(This is a version of a question that I posted earlier ( [deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240772/prism-6-1-slower-than-prism-4) ). That question got deleted because I have been away for a month and unable to respond to comments. I would like to thank the users @StepUp and @Brian Lagunas for the comments they made there, and apologize for not responding to them.)

A month ago I test upgraded an WPF application from using PRISM 4.0 to using PRISM 6.1. For the most part I have just changed the references to the new assemblies, and changed the parts where base-classes and methods had gotten new names.

The application has a main menu that consists of a AnimatedTabControl that is the MainRegion. Then different modules are registered with the main region. These can again consist of different views containing even more views.

What I see after the upgrade to PRISM 6.1, is that switching between views in the AnimatedTabControl takes a lot longer time (the first time) with PRISM 6.1 than it did with PRISM 4. (For one of the modules that has a lot of views in it, the first click has gone from 1,3 seconds (prism 4) to over 5 seconds (prism 6.1).

After some more investigating, I have found that a probable cause for this change in performance, is that the time for when the different constructors for the ViewModels are called, has changed. In the old app with PRISM 4, all the viewmodels under the different views seems to be called at start up of the application, so that loading of look up collections from DB is done then. After upgrading to PRISM 6.1, this loading seems to have been deferred to when the user clicks on a specific menu item the first time.

I wonder if anyone has some pointers as to where I should start looking for a setting that has changed this. Brian Lagunas says that there are no changes in the PRISM framework from 4 to 6.1, so it must be in my application. That might very well be the case, all though I tried not to change any thing else while upgrading. Any pointers are welcome.

regards Gert

Comment: You should never do long running tasks (eg loading from database) in a constructor of an object (here a viewmodel). Provide a Load method (preferably async) to do those jobs.

Comment: @Bart I actually do this in a method, using the BackgroundWorker. The method is however called from the constructor in the viewmodel, I just wrote it this way to simplify. Thank you for your feedback though.